# Solve $x^\prime=x+2y, y^\prime=4x+3y, x(0)=−1, y(0)=1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

Solve $x^\prime=x+2y,  y^\prime=4x+3y,  x(0)=−1,  y(0)=1$

$x(t)= $

$y(t)= $

Find the limits

$\lim_{t \to \infty} x(t)=$

$\lim_{t \to \infty} y(t)= $

Select the appropriate (A, B, or C) that best represents the long time behavior of the solution.

(A) Equilibrium solution

(B) Arc solution

(C) Periodic Solution

This example comes with answers as follows:

$x(t)=-e^{-t}$

$y(t)=e^{-t}$

$\lim_{t \to \infty} x(t)=0$

$\lim_{t \to \infty} y(t)=0$

B

However, the example has no work behind it and I can't find a similar example online or in my textbooks. Would somebody be willing to show me the procedure of how to solve something like this?
Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please use the [mathjax basic tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), review the [meta read](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) and enhance your question. It helps to include context (i.e., your attempts, motivation, etc).

Comment: @Brooke: Can you follow these examples and first solve the system https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/RealEigenvalues.aspx?

Answer (score 1):

You can write the system of ODEs under the following form:

$$
\left[\begin{array}{c}
x^{\prime}\\
y^{\prime}
\end{array}
\right]=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
1&2\\
4&3\end{array}\right]\,\left[\begin{array}{c}
x\\
y
\end{array}\right]
$$

and the solution is given as follows

$$
\left[\begin{array}{c}
x(t)\\
y(t)
\end{array}\right]=\exp(A\,t)\,\left[\begin{array}{c}
x(0)\\
y(0)
\end{array}\right]
$$$$
\exp(A\,t)=L^{-1}\left[(s\,I_{2\times2}-A)^{-1}\right]
$$

where $s$ is the Laplace variable and $L^{-1}$ is the Laplace inverse transform. An example of the calculation of $\exp(A\,t)$ is given in this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RqK_m7qJ_R0

Answer (score 0):

$$x^\prime=x+2y\\ y^\prime=4x+3y
$$ with $x(0)=−1$ and $ y(0)=1$.

Sum both DE:
$$(x+y)'=5(x+y)$$
$$\ln |x+y|=5t+C$$
$$x+y=C_1e^{5t}$$
Now solve the second DE:
$$y'=4x+3y$$
$$y'=4C_1e^{5t}-y$$